# What is equivalent oracle query trunc(date) in Sqlite?

Tags: oracle, sqlite

I need time comparasion.

I store date as sysdate in sqlite "PassTime DATETIME DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')"

i need to compare this value with current day. I could to this in oracle with trunc command. But i don't know how can i do this in sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter a given date or timestamp column on the condition that it fall on today proper you may use:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE PassTime >= DATE('now') AND PassTime < DATE('now', '+1 day');
```

Given that today is 23-Feb-2020, a record with a matching `PassTime` would have a `WHERE` clause looking something like the following:

```
WHERE PassTime > '2020-02-23' AND PassTime < '2020-02-24'
```

So, for example, a `PassTime` of '2020-02-23 12:00:00` would be valid.

Comment: why sqlite don't have proper function for this query? I am going to store another variable only for date and i know that is very bad solution.

Comment: @MuhammedEminoglu Even if SQLite had a truncation date function, you would still want to use the version in my answer because it is sargable.  Keep in mind that SQLite has actual date type.